# Which is better? Carbon or Cocoa? (Mac)

Tags: cocoa, macos, macos-carbon

Which is better for programming? Carbon development or Cocoa development?
Is Carbon Stopped by Apple? Why there is no any new book for Carbon but many new books published for Cocoa?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Cocoa is the way forward, and the only framework that supports GUI development on 64-bit applications. Starting a new application with Carbon would be foolish nowadays.